# How to skip 'composer self-update' but still do 'composer install' with capistrano

Tags: composer-php, capistrano

How to setup the deploy.rb to skip 'composer self-update' but still do 'composer install' with capistrano ?

Can I override the "symfony:composer:install" task on my deploy.rb file ?

I think this task do both 'composer self-update' and 'composer install', but I just want it to do the install.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using capifony you can set a fixed version of composer in your deploy.rb file. That way it will download composer on your server if you don't already have it, but it won't try to update each time you deploy.

Example:

`set :composer_version, "1.3.2"`